# Handling exception on instance creation

Tags: php, exception

Which is the best practice of handling exceptions on instance creation?

Example: I have my custom DB class in which i connect to Oracle Database using PDO extension. When i create instance of `DBModule` class i want to know that connection to `Oracle` is failed.

```
class DBModule
{
    private $pdo;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->checkConnection();
    }

    private function checkConnection()
    {
        if ($this->pdo === null)
        {
            if (!$this->connect())
            {
                if (!$this->reconnect())
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try 
            {
                $this->pdo->query("SELECT 1 FROM Dual");
            } 
            catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                if (!$this->reconnect())
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $thisFunc = basename(__FUNCTION__);

        try
        {
           $this->pdo = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $this->dbName . ";charset=" . $this->charset, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);

           $this->pdo->query("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = '" . $this->nlsDateFormat . "'"); 
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, $thisFunc, $this->logsEnabled, 1, "Failed to connect to DB! errorMessage: " . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function reconnect()
    {
        $thisFunc          = basename(__FUNCTION__);
        $reconnectAtempts  = 0;

        $this->pdo         = null;

        while ($reconnectAtempts <= $this->reconnectMaxAtempts)
        {
            sleep($this->reconnectInterval);

            if ($this->connect())
            {
                return true;
            }

            $reconnectAtempts++;
            $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, $thisFunc, $this->logsEnabled, 3, "Connection is lost, trying to reconnect! reconnectAtempts: " . $reconnectAtempts);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have `checkConnection` itself throw an exception? Side notes: 1) I find it weird/suspicious that a method called `checkConnection` would have any side effects (namely connecting/reconnecting). 2) Unless I'm missing something, `basename(__FUNCTION__)` should always be the same as `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: No exception throws only in connect method

Comment: I meant, make it so that `checkConnection` throws an exception. Note that `connect` isn't throwing anything either, since it handles the exception itself and doesn't throw it back up.

Comment: Ok i will try thank's